# how to filter list items by user/group column in sharepoint?

Tags: list, sharepoint, filter

I have a list that has a user/group column that I want to filter by (the column name is: USERS).
how do I get only the items in the list where the current user exists in the USERS column?

Comment: Do you mean via a caml query or do mean via a customized view?

Answer (score 1):

If it is simply a customized view, look at a Tasks list and the My Items view for reference.

You should be able to go the the Filter section in the view and have a filter that has  "is equal to" "[Me]".  However, it sounds like this is a multi-valued field so maybe you can get away with  "contains" "[Me]".

Another considerations is looking into Audiences if you have MOSS.  The Content Query Web Part is capable of filtering list items based on the audience.

Comment: i tried creating a view and filtering by "[Me]" but it only good for users and not for groups. and i have users & groups mixed together.

Comment: I believe this is wrong. SharePoint 2007 won't let you user the contains operator on a Person or Group column, even if select multiple is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (item["users"] != null)
{
    //get USERS field for item
    SPFieldUserValueCollection fieldUserValueCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, item["users"].ToString());

    //go over the users/groups collection
    foreach (SPFieldUserValue fieldUserValue in fieldUserValueCollection)
    {
        if (fieldUserValue.User == null) //group
        {
            if (web.SiteGroups.GetByID(fieldUserValue.LookupId).ContainsCurrentUser)
            {
                bolItemGood = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else //user
        {
            if (fieldUserValue.User.IsDomainGroup) //domain group
            {
                if (web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(fieldUserValue.LookupId))
                {
                    bolItemGood = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else //sp user
            {
                if (fieldUserValue.User.LoginName == Context.User.Identity.Name)
                {
                    bolItemGood = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```